# Impose variable greater than zero - TI-Nspire CAS

Tags: ti-nspire

Is it possible to impose x>0 in the scratchpad of TI-Nspire CAS? The Define allows only to define a variable x=something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it while defining the variable, but you can use “|” operator to constrain the results of expressions:

```
fMax(0.5*x^3-x-2,x)|x≤1
```

x=-0.816497

```
solve(tan(x)=1/x,x)|x>0 and x<1
```

x=0.86033358901938